# redirecting to subdirectory wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, multisite

I m using Wordpress Multisite option. I had been trying to find a particular solution to my problem on internet, but didnt find any. I m looking for an option that remembers user opted sub-directory, and redirect automatically to this sub-directory on user's next visit to the main domain.

Lets suppose the main domain is (www.example.com) and the sub directory is (www.example.com/toronto). I need to write a code that remembers users chosen sub-directory (www.example.com/toronto), and redirects to it when users access the main website (www.example.com)

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. For those who are searching client side redirect with javascript, can remember their selected option with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (localStorage && localStorage.city1) {
    location = localStorage.city1;    
}

function formChanged(form) {
    var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val !== 'non-value') {
      if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.city1 = val;
      }
      location = val;
    }
 }
</script>

<select onchange="formChanged(this);">
<option value="a">Option A</option>
<option value="b">Option B</option>
<option value="c">Option C</option>
</select>
```

This code will remember the option and include value after the domain name. If value is "a", then it will redirect to www.example.com/a

Hope this will help